# Find an example of a positive function that its improper integral converge, but its series diverge

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, improper-integrals

I need to find an example of a positive function f, and a constant a>0 such that the improper integral of f from 0 to infinity converge, but the series f(na) from 1 to infinity diverge.

Comment: Thinner and thinner spikes around $na$!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on Jyrki's comment, let 
$$f(x)=\begin{cases} 1 &\text{ if there exists an }n\in\mathbb{N}\text{ with } |x-na|\leq \frac{1}{n^2}\\
0 &\text{ otherwise} \end{cases}$$
The graph looks like a sequence of thinner and thinner rectangles above the points $na$.

(1) What is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(na)$?

(2) Show that $\int_0^\infty f(x)\ dx$ is equal to a convergent series.